# How to show $\sum_i(\bar{y}-\hat{y_i})e_i=0$

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

How to show $\sum_i(\bar{y}-\hat{y_i})e_i=0$, I have no trouble to see $$\sum_i(\bar{y}-\hat{y_i})=0,$$ I got stuck at $e_i$ is a random variable, not a constant.

Appreciate any comment

Comment: Is $e_i=y_i-\hat y_i$ ?

Comment: @Henry Thank your for your reply. It should be $\hat{e_i}=y_i-\hat{y_i}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf{y} = (y_1, \cdots, y_n)$ and similarly defined for $\widehat{\mathbf{y}}$. By definition of regression, we have that $\widehat{\mathbf{y}} = \mathbf{H} \mathbf{y}$, where $\mathbf{H} = \mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}^\intercal \mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^\intercal$. Notice that $\mathbf{H} = \mathbf{H}^\intercal$ and $\mathbf{H}^2 = \mathbf{H}$.
\begin{align*}
\sum_i(\overline{y} - \widehat{y}_i)e_i &= (\overline{y}\mathbf{1} - \mathbf{H}\mathbf{y})^\intercal \mathbf{e} \\
&=\left(\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^\intercal \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{H}\mathbf{y}\right)^\intercal \left(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{H}\mathbf{y}\right) \\
&=\mathbf{y}^\intercal\left(\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^\intercal - \mathbf{H}\right)\left(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{H}\right)\mathbf{y} \\
&=\mathbf{y}^\intercal\left(\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^\intercal\right)\left(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{H}\right)\mathbf{y}  - \mathbf{y}\mathbf{H}\left(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{H}\right)\mathbf{y} \\
&= \mathbf{y}^\intercal\left(\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^\intercal\right)\left(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{H}\right)\mathbf{y}  - \mathbf{y}\left(\mathbf{H} - \mathbf{H}^2\right)\mathbf{y}  \\
&= \mathbf{y}^\intercal\left(\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^\intercal\right)\left(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{H}\right)\mathbf{y} \\
&= \overline{y} \sum_i(y_i - \widehat{y}_i) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am a bit dumb in reading matrix form, much appreciated if you can do it in an algebraic way.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are two parts in this equation, since $\sum (\bar{y} - \hat y_i )e_i = \bar y \sum  e_i - \sum \hat y_i e_i = 0$, thus we need to show that $\sum e_i = 0$ and $\sum \hat y_i e_i = 0$, which follows straight from the first order condition of the OLS. Namely,  $\sum e_i = 0$ stems from the derivative of $\sum (y_i - \sum_k \beta_0 - \beta_j x_j)^2$ w.r.t. $\beta_0$, and  $\sum \hat y_i e_i = 0$ from the orthogonality of $\hat y$ and $e$. You can show it, WLOG, by using the $j$th derivative of  $\sum (y_i - \sum_k \beta_0 - \beta_j x_j)^2$ to show that the error term $e$ is orthogonal to each one of the $x$, and therefore to $\hat y$, since $\hat y$ is a linear combination of the $x$s.